# Swift UIImage as button

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm now learning to make an audio recorder app. Basically, I want to add a tap gesture to a UIView to trigger/stop the recording. After triggering my recorder, the image should be changed to another one. My question is:

Am I supposed to control drag two @IBAction functions or only one? How to distinguish the "trigger" and "stop" action? My guess is I may only need one function, and at the beginning of it, I check the image name: if it's the recording icon or the stop icon, and do something accordingly. However, I cannot find the property of UIImage to identify the image it contains.

I'm new to ios so this may not be a good question, but please bear with me. By the way, I'm doing this using interface builder.

Comment: Why not use a flag to toggle the state of recording on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by using `highlightedImage` and `isHighlighted` properties of `UIImageView`. And you can do this by using single `IBAction`

In the `viewDidLoad` method :

```
yourImageView.image = UIImage(name:"RecordImage/TriggerImage")
yourImageView.highlightedImage = UIImage(name:"StopImage")
```

You can set these images in the interface builder too. As you can see in the following image you need set images for both `Image` and `Highlighted` properties.

[image: UIImageView interface builder]

Inside your action method:

```
yourImageView.isHighlighted = !yourImageView.isHighlighted

if yourImageView.isHighlighted
{
  //so now the UIImageView shows stop image that means we are in recording mode
  // do the actions that are to be done in recording mode like start recording updating other UI etc 
}
else
{
 //so now the UIImageView shows Record/Trigger image that means are in normal mode or not recording
  // do the actions that are to be done in normal mode like stop recording (if required )updating other UI etc 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well. So in the interface builder, I just set the "initial" image, and change it to another in code, or I can somehow set both images in the interface builder?

Comment: Updated answer contains image to show how to set the Highlighted image for UIImageView

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `IBAction` for the same and you can check for the image through following code inside the action:

```
if yourImageView.image == UIImage(named: "yourImageName") {
//perform some action here
} else {
//perform some action here 
}
```

Comment: So you are comparing UIImage with String. Is it correct ?

Comment: Actually in swift 3 & swift 4, you can directly paas the image their or you can verify the image by UIImage(named: "yourImageName"). Also please check the edited answer.

Comment: It seems comparing a UIImage with string errors out... The edited answer works well

Comment: @YongliangHe, Thanks buddy! If you find the edited answer useful, then accept it and upvote it. So that other's find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Step1 - declare a property in ViewController class to check the status of button

if is checked = true //recording is going on

if false //recording is stopped

```
//declaration in ViewController class
    var isChecked = false
```

Step 2 - add a button imageView and Assign its button action as below

```
 @IBAction func BottomImageBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        if isChecked {
            //here şet image as stop
        }
        else {
            //here set image as Start
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a global variable declaration. This is an instance property of your view controller.

Comment: It is not global. A global var could be accessed anywhere in your app.

Comment: Why we need another variable while we have the selected(isSelected) property for UIButton?